# How do I use the terminal to log into another mac?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, mount

I have some Bash scripts that copies files from one mac to another trough the LAN, but I need to be logged on to the other mac for the scripts to work. It's a bit cumbersome to go trough Finder to do it, althoug the other mac shows easily enough in the "shared" pane. I want to do it trough the Terminal, just using regular !#/bin/bash.

I notice it is still possible to access another mac trough Finder even though SSH is turned off in the system panel, thus I wonder if there is some other way to do this trough the Terminal, without using SSH.

Edit: Thanks to envalid, I now know that what I want is to **mount** another MacBook trough the terminal, but I'd really like to know how, as my attempts until now have failed.

Comment: By "access another Mac through Finder" do you mean browse the folders and files? View and control the screen? Check System Preferences > Sharing on the Mac you are accessing and tell us what is activated.

Comment: Browse files and folders on the other MacBook trough the terminal. File sharing is activated. SSH will not be activated. Thanks to envalid, I now know not that I'd really like to know how to **mount** another MacBook trough the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mount a computer/partition/image with finder it shows up in `/Volumes/`.

For instance I just mounted a .dmg:

```
ninth:Volumes sakkaku$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root     admin    1 May 19 17:21 Ninth -> /
drwxr-xr-x  9 sakkaku  staff  340 May  4 14:11 ExampleMountedDMG
```

Bonus: You can automate the mounting of volumes by going to System Preferences -> Accounts then click the "login items" tab.  Click the + and select the mounted volume.

Comment: Cool! This might be what I'm looking for. Can't get it to work, though... How do you mount another MacBook trough Terminal?

Comment: Use finder to mount to location then save it to the login items.  Or you could use `mount_afp afp://[username:password]@rhost[:port]/volume destination`

Comment: Where destination is where you want the remote filesystem mounted at

Comment: Honestly if you are going to connect like that you are better off using ssh+sftp, scp, rsync or another protocol as it will be easier IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful. Will regular cp-commands still work trough ssh? And will it be as quick as mount_afp?

Comment: ssh allows you to execute commands on the remote machine.  `cp` and the like do not understand how to talk over ssh.  Rsync will probably offer close to optimal performance, especially since it diffs the files rather then replacing them outright.  Rsync is a little confusing to configure but rocks once it gets going.  [This](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) seems like a decent guide.

Comment: @envalid with ssh you can use scp to copy files. Rsync is awesome but perhaps overkill in some cases.

Comment: Problem with scp is it always has to retransfer the files if they already exist.  Rsync is efficient and fast.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `ssh` to log in to the other machine? Google "ssh tutorial mac" and go "I feel lucky"

Comment: I notice it is still possible to access another mac trough Finder even though SSH is turned off in the system panel, thus I wonder if there is some other way to do this trough the Terminal, without using SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can remotely login to the system by using `ssh <username>@<remote Mac's IP address or hostname>`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your finder works due to some RPC or OS management built into OSX -- that is not related to terminal. SSH is a secure shell (terminal) and is ***the*** way to remotely manage a machine via command line.